# Sqlite3 database file extension

Tags: sqlite, file-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQlite extension name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name)

What is the conventional file extension for an sqlite3 database?

In the question, [SQlite extension name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name), it is claimed there is no conventional name for an sqlite database, but it has been a few years, and i'm wondering if a standard has emerged or barring that if there is a generally accepted standard.

Ultimately what I want to do is make it obvious to future coders what the file is.

I haven't worked very much with sqlite, and so i've never actually seen the file extension in the wild. I want to follow convention if there is one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've often seen `.sqlite`, some tools use `.db3`.

Some example programs that use `.sqlite`:

- Mozilla Firefox
- Mozilla Thunderbird
- Several Addons for Mozilla applications
- Mumble

A similar question: [What is the best extension name SQlite database files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name)

Comment: I had to use .s3db for "SQLite Administrator."