# what's the difference between .db and sqlite3 extensions?

Tags: sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQlite extension name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name)

The title is definitely the question. So, when I start to manage an sqlite database, so I am getting the options how to save file on disk. I mean the extension .db or .sqlite(3). So, is the some difference, restrictions or other issues.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my past sqlite naming i used .db extension but when i read this post below i change it to .sqlite3db. i add db to specify that the file is an sqlite3 database.

[SQlite extension name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name)

and check the answer of Brian Campbell

Hope this help.

Regards