# Creating and managing *.db files using VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net

I have seen a few .NET apps use .db files. I am not new to Visual Basic, however I have never created a VB app that uses databases. I do know PHP pretty well, and working with databases in PHP I am familiar with.

I have searched and tried different examples, but I mostly keep coming across .mdb files. This IS NOT what I want.

So I need pointers to tutorials or examples that show how to create a .db file, and run queries on it, in Visual Basic .NET (2010). I don't need source code, I can get that, I just need to know what I am looking for so I can Google it.

Comment: The DB extension is associated to numerous applications. Supposing you are interested in database then you are probably referencing to SQLite databases. Try to search on that.

Comment: I have been playing with dotconnect from devart for SQLite. I am struggling to find good examples for it. I have playing around with it all night.

What I am trying to get out of it: I have my program analyzing a file and parsing each line and putting it into a listview. My test file has about 1,000 lines. A real working file, could have upwards of 5-10k lines. For each line, I want it to also store that data into the database.

Here is a psuedocode:

Load file
Connect to db

for each ...
 add to listview
 add to database
next

done
close database

I already have all the code, now just the db

Comment: Can you show some of your code and where you have the problem? You need to know how to put one record (line) inside a table?

Comment: I know how to do that, given I find a good SQL system for VB.NET. It appears that dotconnect from devart doesn't support retrieving datatables with their free version. I'm not going to pay money for this when I am sure there are free ones somewhere.

I tried another SQLite system that I found, but it was a sq3db file or something like that. It needs to be a .db file.

I am not needing code, I can write the code, I am having a hard time finding a good free sql management for VB.NET that uses .db files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between sq3db and db extension regarding SQLite.
You could find here [a discussion on SQLite database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name)

To access you db file then you could use the free library provided by
[system.data.sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was thinking that the sqlite only used the sq3db files. I have seen apps use .db and to me, visually I prefer the .db extension. I snagged the sqlite admin program, but it was only able to save as sq3db files, hence why I was confused. Thank you for your answer and support! I am downloading the extension for .net 4 to play around with it.