# Using sql lite database in my android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I created a database using DB browser. I should copy the file in assets folder. What should be the extension of the file?

Comment: It should be anything sample : data.db , data.sql or ,data  .

Comment: What is reason to store your database file in the assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database file can be visible to the user, there are [several possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name) to show that the file is an SQLite 3 file.

However, on Android, database files are stored in a separate directory, and typically not visible as files.
Therefore, there is *no* requirement or even recommendation for a file extension. In practice, many apps do not use an extension; but you can use whatever makes sense for you.

Answer (score -1):

It should be anything. The recommended is `.db`