# C# SQLite file format base.data

Tags: c#, sqlite

[image]I want to open a .data file. I use SQLite Studio. The file is opened normally.
But if you try to print data into DataGrid in the WInForms application, but it crashes out that it's not a database file

```
string connString = @"Data Source=AdLoc.data; Version=3";
const string query = "SELECT * FROM Person";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();
using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command))
{
   adapter.Fill(ds);
}


dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: have you tried renaming the file to ***.db ?? SQLite should not actually care about the files extension - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/what-is-the-best-extension-name-sqlite-database-files

Comment: What is the exact exception?

Comment: Add the exception and in which line it happens to your post. By the way check you already give the correct path to your database full/relative path!

Comment: Don't post screenshots of errors. Post the error text itself.

Comment: @BassemAkl - Educated guess says that if the file path was incorrect, it'd be throwing some sort of "File not found" exception.  Best guess is the source file isn't formatted in a manner that SQLite can correctly deal with.